# How to avoid calls to the DB on each type?

Tags: javascript

I am working on an App where the user has 2 inputs, in one of the inputs the user types numbers, and in the other input appears a calculation. So, in each number that the user types in the inputs, there is a call to the DB, and I want to avoid that. I want to give time, so the user can type in the input, and after that, the call to the DB is done.

this is the function which is in a service

```
applyStraightRisk = function(slip, amount) {
      applyStraightRiskWin({
        wagerType: '1',
        riskOrWin: 'RISK',
        riskValue: amount,
        winValue: slip.win || 0,
        amount: amount,
        selections: [slip]
      });
    }, applyStraightWin = function(slip, amount) {
      applyStraightRiskWin({
        wagerType: '1',
        riskOrWin: 'WIN',
        riskValue: slip.risk,
        winValue: amount,
        amount: amount,
        selections: [slip]
      });
    }

return {
  riskWinCalculations: function(params, scope, index) {
    switch (params.type) {
      case 'RISKSTRAIGHT':
        applyStraightRisk(params.slip, params.slip.risk);
        break;
      case 'WINSTRAIGHT':
        applyStraightWin(params.slip, params.slip.win);
        break;
  };
}
```

I was thinking in do it with a `$timeout/setTimeout`, but, is there any other better way?

Comment: you can check the debounce function in underscore.js http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'debounce' function form the [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) library.

```
    applyStraightRisk = _.debounce(function(slip, amount) {
    ...
    }, 500); // Maximum run of once per 500 milliseconds
```

Code for this function if you only need it (from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html))

```
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout, args, context, timestamp, result;

  var later = function() {
    var last = _.now() - timestamp;

    if (last < wait && last >= 0) {
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait - last);
    } else {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) {
        result = func.apply(context, args);
        if (!timeout) context = args = null;
      }
    }
  };

  return function() {
    context = this;
    args = arguments;
    timestamp = _.now();
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    if (!timeout) timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) {
      result = func.apply(context, args);
      context = args = null;
    }

    return result;
  };
};
```

As you can see, it uses setTimeout.

Comment: perrrrrrrrrrrrrrfect, I am actually using `Lodash`, but it has the same effect. thanks :)